# cakephp v2 - Finding Duplicates using name field

Tags: mysql, cakephp

My Sql skills are lacking and would really appreciate the help. What is the most efficient way to pull all records where a field is the same?

For example my tables name is 'games' and has an association with the table 'consoles'

How do I pull all record of games with the same (duplicate) 'name', retain associations and be able to access all fields.

Basically modify this to just show duplicates:

```
$this->set('games', $this->Game->find('all', array('order' => array('Game.name' => 'asc'))));
```

Is there an easy way to do this using cake or how would I do it through sql using query()?

Much appreciated in advance!

Regards,
Ash

Comment: In SQL, you usually join the table against itself: `SELECT ID,name from games g1 JOIN games g2 where g1.name = g2.name and g1.ID <> g2.ID` - but I don't know cake.

Comment: @Konerak tried testing your query and it is extremely taxative as it is, it works on a small base but my test with 2200 games crashed.

Comment: Can you post the structure you are trying to obtain?? I'm not sure I understand you, but I guess you should try using `'group'` option in `find()`, or maybe `'DISTINCT'`. Read about them [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

Comment: Say I have 2 Games. Zelda: A Link to the Past. Same title. 

I want to grab those two games with all associations and be able to display them in the same index I had used previously in my view. As one Zelda game may have a manual with it, while another might not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to use Konerak query, it worked but only on small tables, on my test base with 2k records it crashed on sql client and gives a memory error on php (I used a non indexed field for testing). If it works for you:

```
$options = array();
$options['joins'][0]['table'] = 'games';
$options['joins'][0]['alias'] = 'Game2';
$options['joins'][0]['conditions'] = array(1 => 1);
$options['conditions'] = 'Game.name = Game2.name';
$options['conditions']['NOT'] = 'Game.id = Game2.id';
$options['order'] = 'Game.name ASC';

//$this->Game->contain();
$this->set('games', $this->Game->find('all', $options));
```

/*

This solutions use 2 queries but I managed to test it just fine:

```
$options = array();
$options['fields'] = 'Game.name';
$options['group'] = 'Game.name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1';

// get all the names > 1
//$this->Game->contain();
$regs = $this->Game->find('all', $options);

// make a nice array with them
$names = array();
foreach ($regs as $reg) {
$names[] = $reg['Game']['name'];
}

// and search for only those games
//$this->Game->contain();
$this->set('games', $this->Game->find('all', array(
                                     'conditions' => array('Game.name' => $names), 
                                     'order' => 'name ASC')));
```

Let me know if that won't work for you and what problems you are having.

edit. I commented the `contain` lines. Seems you want all the structure so you wouldn't need them anyway.

edit2. remove possible ambiguity on field names.

Comment: Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'contain' at line 1

Comment: @MasaAsh If you aren't using containable behavior you should remove those lines: (`$this->Game->contain();`). I always use it and sometimes forget that it isn't enabled by default. =P

Comment: Haha, Ok, Now I am getting this error.

Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: @MasaAsh Seems you have in your structure more models with the name field and they are clashing. Identify the query getting the error and change `'name'` TO `'Game.name'`. I updated the awnser to reflect it.

Comment: Wahoo. I can't thank-you enough. The order was giving me the last error. Simply changed it to 'order' => 'Game.name ASC'

You are a fantastic human being. Thanks for being a cool internets guru.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if cake has a built in way to represent this but you can do it with this MySQL Method.

```
$this->set('games', $this->Game->query('SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count FROM games GROUP BY name HAVING count > 1');
```

You can include any fields you want in the select.

---

UPDATED

This would be the CakePHP way of doing it and the results are formatted a little better:

```
$this->set('games', $this->Game->find('all',array('fields'=>array('name','COUNT(*) as count'), 'group'=>'name', 'having'=>'count > 1')));
```

Comment: This does work to get the duplicates, but the data is not how I want it to be returned. I don't want to have to rewrite my index's. 

With your suggestion the data is returned as the following

array(
 (int) 0 => array(
  'games' => array(
   'name' => 'Astrosmash'
  ),

Comment: Updated my answer, but it looks like @petervaz has a better solution.

Comment: Yup, Timed out. Thanks for the help though. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont have enough rep to comment on his answer but you need to add `Game.name` when you reference the name field because another one of your related tables is using a `name` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function admin_duplicate_account() {
    $this->User->unBindModel(array('hasOne' => array('Admin')));
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        // pr($this->request->data); exit;
        if ($this->request->data['User']['email'] == 1) {
            $arr_having = array();
            $arr_having['fields'] = 'User.email';
            $arr_having['group'] = 'User.email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1';

            $regs = $this->User->find('all', $arr_having, array('conditions' => array('User.role' => array('U', 'P'), 'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive'))));
            $names = array();
            foreach ($regs as $reg) {

                if ($reg['User']['email']) {
                    $names[] = $reg['User']['email'];
                }
            }

            $this->set('allusers', $this->User->find('all', array(
                        'conditions' => array('User.email' => $names, 'User.role' => array('U', 'P'), 'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive')))));
        }


        if ($this->request->data['User']['first_name'] == 1) {
            $arr_having = array();
            $arr_having['fields'] = 'PersonalInformation.first_name';
            $arr_having['group'] = 'PersonalInformation.first_name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1';

            $regs = $this->User->find('all', $arr_having, array('conditions' => array('User.role' => array('U', 'P'), 'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive'))));

            //pr($regs); exit;
            $names = array();
            foreach ($regs as $reg) {

                if ($reg['PersonalInformation']['first_name']) {
                    $names[] = $reg['PersonalInformation']['first_name'];
                }
                //$names[] = $reg['PersonalInformation']['first_name'];
            }
            //pr($names); 
            $data = $this->User->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('PersonalInformation.first_name' => $names, 'User.role' => array('U', 'P'), 'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive'))));
            //pr($data); exit;

            $this->set('allusers', $data);
        }



        if ($this->request->data['User']['last_name'] == 1) {

            $arr_having = array();
            $arr_having['fields'] = 'PersonalInformation.last_name';
            $arr_having['group'] = 'PersonalInformation.last_name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1';

            $regs = $this->User->find('all', $arr_having, array('conditions' => array('User.role' => array('U', 'P'), 'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive'))));

            //pr($regs); exit;
            $names = array();
            foreach ($regs as $reg) {

                if ($reg['PersonalInformation']['last_name']) {
                    $names[] = $reg['PersonalInformation']['last_name'];
                }
                //$names[] = $reg['PersonalInformation']['first_name'];
            }
            //pr($names); 
            $data = $this->User->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('PersonalInformation.last_name' => $names, 'User.role' => array('U', 'P'), 'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive'))));
            //pr($data); exit;

            $this->set('allusers', $data);
        }


        if ($this->request->data['User']['primary_phone'] == 1) {

            $arr_having = array();
            $arr_having['fields'] = 'PersonalInformation.primary_phone';
            $arr_having['group'] = 'PersonalInformation.primary_phone HAVING COUNT(*) > 1';

            $regs = $this->User->find('all', $arr_having, array('conditions' => array('User.role' => array('U', 'P'), 'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive'))));

            //pr($regs); exit;
            $names = array();
            foreach ($regs as $reg) {

                if ($reg['PersonalInformation']['primary_phone']) {
                    $names[] = $reg['PersonalInformation']['primary_phone'];
                }

            }
            //pr($names); 
            $data = $this->User->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('PersonalInformation.primary_phone' => $names, 'User.role' => array('U', 'P'), 'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive'))));
            //pr($data); exit;

            $this->set('allusers', $data);
        }
        if ($this->request->data['User']['dob'] == 1) {


            $arr_having = array();
            $arr_having['fields'] = 'PersonalInformation.dob';
            $arr_having['group'] = 'PersonalInformation.dob HAVING COUNT(*) > 1';

            $regs = $this->User->find('all', $arr_having, array('conditions' => array('User.role' => array('U', 'P'), 'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive'))));

            //pr($regs); exit;
            $names = array();
            foreach ($regs as $reg) {

                if ($reg['PersonalInformation']['dob']) {
                    $names[] = $reg['PersonalInformation']['dob'];
                }
            }
            //pr($names); 
            $data = $this->User->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('PersonalInformation.dob' => $names, 'User.role' => array('U', 'P'), 'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive'))));
            //pr($data); exit;

            $this->set('allusers', $data);
        }
    } else {

        $this->set('allusers', $this->User->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array('User.role' => array('U', 'P'), 'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive')))));
    }

    $this->layout = 'admin';
}
```

Comment: can find specific fields